# Eclipse formatting cause CSS to stop working

Tags: eclipse, css, css-selectors, formatter

I have following CSS in my style.css:

```
.btfl-alert-warning:not(.selectize-control):not(.selectize-dropdown-content):not(.selectize-dropdown)
{
    //some properties
}
```

Now, when I use Eclipse formatting, eclipse make space between 'not' and parenthesis and I get something like this:

```
.btfl-alert-warning:not (.selectize-control ):not (.selectize-dropdown-content
    ):not (.selectize-dropdown ) {

}
```

After using formatter second time it looks much worse, but the point is after adding this 'space' this selector just stop work. I checked all CSS formatter options in Eclipse but nothing helped me.

Do you have any idea how to prevent ruining this CSS?

Comment: Your best bet is to just avoid autoformatting your CSS.

Comment: @BoltClock I have ~10developers in team and this file is called style.css, we are going to develop this project for next 12 months. Its not easy to guarantee that nobody by mistake wont run formatting on this file.. One option i am thinking about is to try separate this css to another file and import it in my style.css, but maybe someone has better idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using additional css file called style_do_not_format.css which contains only that css and comment about not formatting this file because it cause css to stop work. 
In my style.css file i use

```
@IMPORT url("style_do_not_format.css");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go to Preferences -> CSS -> Code Style:
Then modify it as you want it to show.

In the case you can't make it in the CSS(Code Style), you might don't apply the format in eclipse, it is fine to do all the work in Eclipse, once you finish when you have a production ready CSS/HTML/JS/.... you can use [atom](https://atom.io/) from GitHub to apply format to your CSS/HTML/JS/.... use the plugins from [AtomLinter](https://atom.io/users/AtomLinter)

I hope this helps you.